# Clear (or delete?) all COM port by programing

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

All I found the way to remove unused COM port is use device manager, right-click it and remove.

But I need to remove them by c/c++.

I tried to delete reg Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports but it's not work.

I want to do that like COM Name Arbiter Tool, just one click then I can remove them all.

I don't need interface, just run the program and remove all COM port, then I can reuse those ports.

I come from Taiwan and not so good at English, I'm sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: You can access the register through Windows API function calls, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/. `RegDeleteKey`, `RegDeleteTree` and so on.